# Download a file from internet using c++ and sdl2

Tags: c++, sdl2

I am using the SDL2 libs. I want to know how to download an mp3 file from a weblink (from my website) and use it in game (i know how to play songs but not how to download them).
Obviously these songs are not copyrighted..
Can you give me example code using sdl2_net ? Thanks

Comment: FYI: I've deleted my answer as it was invalid. I'll try to find time to fix the posted code and will update it later.

Comment: Don't worry... i am searching something on youtube about multiplayer game and so if i can do this i will be able to do downloads too

Comment: SDL_net only provides low level socket functionality. You'd have to implement HTTP(S) on top of that. I highly recommend you use a library like libcurl, cpp-netlib or cpr for accessing the web.